# What would the theoretical barometric pressure be at the bottom of a canyon that is about 15 miles below Earth's surface?

Tags: pressure, temperature, atmospheric-science, geophysics

I'm trying to create a fictional world. I am kicking around the idea of supercritical CO2 lifeforms that live at the bottom of some abyss. I read that supercritical CO2 must be at 88F and 72atm.
I am trying to find the depth at which these conditions would hold. I only need a psuedo-scientific explanation, but I would like to be somewhere in the ballpark of believability. Assume a planet that is mostly earthlike, maybe a little bigger (or the same if it is easier). The place in question is not a tunnel but a canyon or abyss that is miles wide. I would like the territory of the CO2 lifeforms to overlap at least somewhat with conditions a human could survive in (not necessarily thrive).
My thinking is that in a tunnel the temperature would increase too fast for humans to survive. Since there is an open top, it would be well ventilated and the imagination could be stretched for humans to survive there, I think. I just have no idea how to calculate the barometric pressure of an open-aired location that far down.
Please share any calculations, suggestions, or thoughts you have.

Comment: You can use the Barometric formula, wich you can find in wiki or  google. But you have to go much deeper than 15miles, and the temperature will go up and not down

Comment: This would be more suited to our [worldbuilding.se] stack which exists specifically for the purpose helping artists/writers/game-designers develop the rules and parameters of their fictional world. Whilst you're at it, check out all the rest of the [many sites on the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Be sure to take their tour and read up in their help centres *before posting* - as you should on any site on the SE network. You might have more luck with clathrate-hydrates than CO2.

Comment: [Messinian salinity crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messinian_salinity_crisis)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645580/123208 I'm not sure why my answer there got downvoted, but I suspect it's because of my remarks about solid air.